# Laravel 5 - How to use same user authentication for multiple sub domains?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, subdomain

I have a primary domain www.mysite.com and one sub domain test.mysite.com.
Both the web applications are developed in Laravel 5.1 and in different folders (occupy the same server).

If the user is logged in through www.mysite.com login page, then the user should not have to login while going to test.mysite.com else the user should login through www.mysite.com login page.

How can I use the same user authentication session for both in www.mysite.com and test.mysite.com?

Hope for a best solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know its the best solution for this but, you can use OAUTH2.
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel